# mod_rewrite keep square brackets in URL

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use mod_rewrite to rewrite a URL but keep the square brackets as it's required by the script to process:

```
RewriteRule ^(order|cart)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /cart?a=add&pid=$2&addons\[$3\] [L,NE]
```

Unfortunately, the above URL gets translated as follows:
from: `https://example.com/order/1/5`  to `https://example.com/cart?a=add&pid=1&addons%5B7%5D=`

This is what I need as the URL result:
from `https://example.com/order/1/5` to `https://example.com/cart?a=add&pid=1&addons[5]`

I need the square brackets `[$3]` to stay as square brackets in the URL instead of being changed in mod_rewrite to escaped characters %5B and %5D. No, adding the backslashes does nothing to fix this. I also tried the "B" flag and others.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected result?Please do add that.

Comment: @Mandy8055 just edited to add that

Comment: Punctuations can't be used in URLs? What about the dot in index.html? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The `NE` flag is the correct one but it's probably confused by the fact you escape the square brackets in your rule. The second argument is not a regular expression and you don't have to escape these.

So, this should work:

```
RewriteRule ^(order|cart)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /cart?a=add&pid=$2&addons[$3] [L,NE]
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's what I tried first and it didn't work. The square brackets still get converted to escaped chars %5B and %5D with or without the backslash

Comment: Keep in mind redirects get cached by your browser. Make sure your empty your cache after each change to your rules.

Comment: yes I tried using private browsing only. Any other suggestions? Maybe using RewriteMap?

Comment: RewriteMaps are just mapping collections, it's not going to solve that. When trying in private browsing, you opened a new private window every time? The same private window will cache stuff. Can you also try to add the R flag and see if the URL you end up with is encoded?

Comment: yes I opened a brand new private window each time as I was familiar with the caching issue. The "R" flag unfortunately did not change anything, still encodes the square brackets...

Comment: That is so bizarre... I just tested on my setup and it works as intended with the NE flag. When removing the flag it encodes them. I'm starting to think you have another rule impacting this? Can you try the same rule in a dummy vhost on the same server or within another folder with a blank root htaccess?

Comment: thanks for testing. I did try again from a blank folder with no other mod_rewrite rules and it still encodes the square brackets for me. I'm using LiteSpeed web server, but it's a drop-in replacement for Apache so shouldn't affect anything... not sure what else to do!

Comment: Looks like a LiteSpeed bug to me, or at least it doesn't support all the Apache flags. Ask on https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/forum/forums/apache-migration-compatibility.24/ maybe?